# Собою/собой, мною/мной

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правда, что, например, на экзамене лучше не писать так?

`Он мною пользовался.`

`Он собою создал память на века.`

И правда ли, что надо писать так (на экзамене, в официальном контексте)?

`Он мной пользовался.`

`Он собой создал память на века.`

Или это не так, как с *нету* и *щас*? (Эти слова злые, придирчивые экзаменаторы, как известно, не любят-таки.)

Comment: не думаю, что где-либо так "надо" писать.

Comment: На века – раздельно.

Comment: "Эти", а не "это".

Comment: Это зависит от строгости требований.

Comment: Ко второму предложению экзаменаторы точно придерутся. Очень криво звучит.

Comment: Да, правда надо писать *на века*, которое я с *навеки* перепутал.

Comment: Согласились, что раздельно, но так и не поправили.

Comment: Забыл тогда, а сейчас – сделал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможные варианты:

*Он ***мной*** пользовался* (разг. и нейтр.)

*Он ***собою*** создал память на века* (высок.)

[**ГРАМОТА.РУ**](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=-%D0%BE%D1%8E)

**Вопрос 1.**  Правильно ли употребление слова "длиною" или здесь (тех. текст) должно быть "длиной"?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. В **технических** текстах формы творительного падежа на -ою употреблять не рекомендуется.

**Вопрос 2.**  Он [Международный женский день] дышит молодостью, долгожданной свежестью и красотой. Правильно «красотой» или «красотою»?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Оба варианта правильны. Однако в современном языке (в отличие от языка XIX века) варианты форм творительного падежа ед. числа на -ою, -ею (красотою, картою, зарею и т. д.) употребляются очень редко и носят **книжный** оттенок.

**Вопрос 3.**  В каких случаях в окончаниях имен **существительных и местоимений** в творительном падеже пишется -ой и -ою? Например, тобой - тобою, душой - душою.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Это **вариантные** окончания. Более **употребительно** окончание -ОЙ: тобой, душой.

**[РОЗЕНТАЛЬ](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/57.htm#%D0%B7_12)**

§157. Окончания творительного падежа единственного и множественного числа.

В парах зимой – зимою, страной – страною, доро́гой – доро́гою вторая форма является **архаичной.**

**[Приложение](https://ru.anyquestion.info/a/evolyutsiya-padezhnoy-sistemy-russkogo-yazyka-analiz-fleksii-oyu-u-suschestvitelnyh)**

**Эволюция падежной системы русского языка**: анализ флексии -ою у существительных